# Call gnome-session via windows command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gnome

I am trying to create a batch file that will automatically launch my gnome desktop via VsXsrv

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File FILE_PATH
wsl gnome-session
```

Starting VsXsrv works just fine, but `wsl gnome-session` does not work.
I tried inputting it manually in the command prompt, but it does not work: the only way I have to make it work is first launching my wsl via `wsl`, and then writing the command `$ gnome-session`.
Is there a way to make this fit inside a batch file on windows 10?

Comment: I am betting you will find your answer in [Microsoft's Command Reference for Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/reference)

Comment: @Squashman hi, thank you for you comment. I have already checked that page out. Normal commands such as `wsl -e dir` just works fine, the issue just occours with `gnome-session`.